# getting xml attributes php

Tags: php, xml, api

I am trying to connect to an API system and it uses XML for communicate. When I try to get a request the API returns me a XML string like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
  <response xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
    <result code="1000">
      <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <resData xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
      <domain:chkData xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
        <domain:cd>
          <domain:name normalized_name="dasfasfgg" canonized_name="dasfasfgg" tld="ir" avail="1">dasfasfgg.ir</domain:name>
        </domain:cd>
      </domain:chkData>
    </resData>
    <trID>
      <clTRID>TEST-12345</clTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
```

I want to get the `avail` attribute on the `domain:name` namespace. I tried this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$attrs = $xml->domain->attributes();
```

but in returns an empty object. how can I get the attributes?

Comment: `domain` is a __namespace__.

Comment: @u_mulder edited.

Comment: Now, start using some search `parse xml namespaces` or similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not the most elegant way but:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); // as response I understand given xml as string
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

$value = $xml->response->resData->children($namespaces['domain'])->chkData->cd->name->attributes()->avail[0];
```

Comment: This returns the exact value. I can also get other attributes easily. Thanks

Comment: Your code should not depend on `getNamespaces()` - it is mostly a debug function. The returned array can be different for any XML element (even of the same document). Define a fixed array (or class constants) for the namespace URIs.